# i want Legacy server key to add to my admin panel for cloud messaging

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I cant find legacy server key on cloud messaging in firebase as shown in the image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Firebase [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#fcm):

> FCM no longer creates legacy server keys.
>   Existing legacy server keys will continue to work, but we recommend that you instead use the newer version of key labeled Server key in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/).
>
> For more information, see [Migrate legacy server keys](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#migrate-legacy-server-keys).